# List Object with multiple "keys" in it

Tags: java, arrays, list, hashmap, swt

Hoi,

currently I have a List in Java where I add Entrys via `list.add("Example");`

But now I would like to add IDs to each entry. I could do this via

```
list.put("Example XY");
list.setData("Example XY", 1);
```

But in my lists there are a lot of duplicate "Names". So they Keys for the names get overriden because it seems that I cant set duplicate keys in it.

Somebody got an Idea how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really think about using a [`ListViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FListViewer.html) instead. A `ListViewer` can contain any bean object you want and show any of it's fields as the text in the `List`.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SampleListViewer.htm) is an example of a `ListViewer`.

---

It's definitely a lot more code, but it will be worth it in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `HashMap`, if you would like to store the key - value pair in the collection

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test1 {     

    public static void main( String [] args) 
    {     
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("1", "Example XY");
        map.put("2", "Example XZ");
    } 
}
```

**Note**: you can not have duplicate values for key

Comment: Then how would he get the id for "Example XY"? Iterating over all keys is not a good solution...

Comment: The OP can use MultiMap and it would solve the issue. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)

Use `MultiMap<String, String>`

```
Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

  // Adding some key/value
  myMultimap.put("E1", "One");
  myMultimap.put("E1", "Two");
  myMultimap.put("E1", "Three");
  myMultimap.put("E2", "AnotherOne");

  // Getting the size
  int size = myMultimap.size();
  System.out.println(size);  // 4

  // Getting values
  Collection<string> sample = myMultimap.get("E1");
  System.out.println(E1); // [One, Two, Three];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider what it means when an object has the same key.  If it's not the same object than the key you are using is wrong.  You could add the data to the objects instead of using strings and then have a list with multiples of each "name"

```
List l = new ArrayList<SomeObject>;

list.put(new SomeObject("red ball", 1))
list.put(new SomeObject("red ball", 2))
```

or make a map of lists of values

```
Map<String,List<SomeObject>> = new HashMap<String,List<SomeObject>>;
    map.get("Red Ball")==null ? map.put(new ArrayList<SomeObject>(){{ add(x) }})
                              : map.get("Red Ball").add(x);
```

Personally I prefer solution 1.